# Difference between sudo group and sudoers file?

Tags: ubuntu

I am creating a user in Ubuntu 14.04 using command `adduser`.

I want to give it **sudo** access. For doing this, I am consfused in between two ways.

First way is : If I add that user to sudo group using command `usermod -aG sudo`.

Second way is : If I edit the sudoers file using command `visudo` and add a line `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.

Please clear the confusion between these two.

Answer (score 19):

`sudo` group is not special by itself. It has sudo access because (if) there's a line like this in the `sudoers` file:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So it's the file that really matters anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu default `/etc/sudoers` configuration has two groups to allow sudo access.  Members of these groups are allowed sudo access without requiring an edit to `/etc/sudoers` or the addition of a configuration file to `/etc/sudoers.d`.

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The preferred way to do local configuration addition is to add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d` with the required configuration.  This allows the default configuration to be updated automatically.  Use `visudo` to at least verify these changes