# Add a user with permissions to install programs but without permissions to access the directories of other users

Tags: linux, permissions, sudoers, users

I need to create an user in a Linux system with permissions to install programs but without permissions to access the directories of other users.

I've tried to do this:

```
# Create restricted user user
adduser --home /home/restricted_user restricted_user

# Edit normal user dir permissions
chmod -R 700 /home/normal_user/

# Add restricted user to sudoers in order to allow program installation
sudo adduser restricted_user sudo
```

Then, I tried:

```
su restricted_user
sudo ls /home/normal_user
```

And finally the restricted user has access to the normal user's directory if he does it with sudo

How can I implement this restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the user to the [`sudo` group](https://superuser.com/a/1239833/432690), do not grant them general root access. Edit `/etc/sudoers` and specify a small set of executables the user can run as root. Example:

```
# in sudoers file
restricted_user ALL = (root) /usr/bin/apt-get
restricted_user ALL = (root) /sbin/reboot
```

Notes:

- Depending on your Linux: `apt-get`/`apt`, `dpkg`, `opkg`, `pacman`, `yum`, …
- Use full paths.
- The right way to edit `sudoers` is [`visudo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27595/108618).
- See `man 5 sudoers` for more information on the syntax.
- When building more complex rules remember their [order matters](https://superuser.com/a/1328457/432690).

Keep in mind a determined user who can install arbitrary programs is able to prepare and install a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_an_executable_file) version of `ls` or "upgraded" `sudo` that will grant them root access regardless of `/etc/sudoers`. Or provide and install a package that performs arbitrary operations when being installed (possibly without actually installing anything). Preventing this may not be easy.